# Polynomial roots. Finite Extensions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, extension-field, roots-of-unity

If $a,b,c$ belong to $\mathbb Q$ and $ω^3=1$ is a third root of unity, then prove that if $$(a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4})^3=1+2\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{4}$$ holds we also have 
$$ 1+2ω\sqrt[3]{2}-\bar ω\sqrt[3]{4}=(a+bω\sqrt[3]{2}+c\bar ω\sqrt[3]{4})^3
.$$ (Not sure about the third power on the right hand side  notes are not clear.)

How can I avoid brute force calculation in things like this? They pop everywhere in field extensions - Galois theory. If a polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ has a root $λ=1+2\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{4}$ then prove it has also the roots $λ'=1+2ω\sqrt[3]{2}-\bar ω\sqrt[3]{4}$, $λ''=1+2 \bar ω\sqrt[3]{2}-ω\sqrt[3]{4}$.

Comment: Where does $\omega$ play into this?

Comment: Dunno maybe through a theorem  or something that connects roots of unity. and maybe cyclotomic polynomials of n degree.And all that with splitting fields.

Comment: yeah, but your question is about rational numbers and how they cube to something involving just $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and its powers.

Comment: check the whole question !!I need to prove something about the other roots of a polynomial that involves omega

Comment: I did, I don't see the logical link between the two. You know nothing about $a,b,c$ or at least nothing about them is stated in the problem. Clearly this is not true for **every** $a,b,c\in\Bbb Q$, so that cannot be proved at all as you have stated it, with or without $\omega$.

Comment: Maybe you mean "find $a,b,c \in \Bbb{Q}$ such that <equation>"?

Comment: OOOOHHH you where right let me edit my question .Im a bit tired sorry trying to translate and write in latex.

Comment: IT is FIxed !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3] 2,\zeta_3)$ which is the splitting field of $x^2 - 2$ over $\mathbb Q$. Since that polynomial is irreducible, it follows that there is an automorphism of $K$ over $\mathbb Q$ which takes $\sqrt[3] 2$ to $\zeta_3 \sqrt[3] 2$. Call it $\sigma$. For clarity let $\sqrt[3] 2 = \alpha$ and $\zeta = \zeta_3$, so $\sigma(\alpha) = \zeta\alpha$.

We know that

$$(a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4})^3=1+2\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{4}$$

Equivalently:
$$ a + b \alpha + c\alpha^2 = 1 + 2 \alpha - \alpha^2$$

Since $\sigma$ is an automorphism (thus well defined, and also making the relationship if and only if), it should preserve this equality:
$$\Leftrightarrow \sigma(a + b \alpha + c\alpha^2 = 1 + 2 \alpha - \alpha^2) = \sigma(a + b \alpha + c\alpha^2 = 1 + 2 \alpha - \alpha^2)$$

Distribute $\sigma$ according to the ring homomorphism rules, and recognize that it fixes $a,b,c$ because they are in $\mathbb Q$.

$$\Leftrightarrow a + b \sigma(\alpha) + c (\sigma(\alpha))^2 = 1 + 2\sigma(\alpha) - (\sigma(\alpha))^2$$

Now recognize that $\sigma \alpha = \zeta\alpha = \omega \sqrt[3] 2$ in your notation. Its square is $\zeta^2 \alpha^2$: but $\zeta^2$ is another third root of unity, and $\zeta^2\zeta = 1$, so $\zeta^2 = \zeta^{-1} = \bar \zeta$, and so we get $\bar \omega \sqrt[4] 3$ exactly as you have.

I think you can see how this generalizes to other situations.

Comment: Perfect.Thank you.One thing only.Why K is the splitting field how do i know there is not a subfield that my polynomial also splits? And why is K the splitting field how do i know $sqrt{2}$ is in there

Comment: ANd what about the second part .Im new to these things sorry for asking too much.

Comment: If you have splits you definitely have two roots, then you can call one $\alpha$ and the other $\zeta\alpha$. You can divide to get $\alpha$ and $\zeta$, and together those two clearly generate all of the roots.

Answer (score 1):

You largely cannot avoid explicit (tedious) calculation.  You are at various times determining whether two vector spaces intersect, determining whether an element from a vector space is in a subvector space, et c.

In this particular case, you ask whether a particular algebraic number will always appear as a root with some other algebraic number.  Note that conjugate roots (relative to a base field) always occur together as roots of any polynonmial (with coefficients in that base field).  For instance, of polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb{Q}$, $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ are conjugate roots and always appear together.  You might already know that a minimal polynomial contains the conjugate roots.  (The Galois group of the splitting field of the minimal polynomial transitively maps the algebraic number you care about to all the other roots of the minimal polynomial.)

So, can you find the minimal polynomial of $1+2 \sqrt[3]{2} - \sqrt[3]{4}$?
(It's $x^3 - 3x^2+15x-25$.)
Can you divide this root from that and factor the result?
(The quotient is $x^2 - (2-2\sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{4})x + 5+5\sqrt[3]{2}$ and factoring quadratics is straightforward.  This is where $\omega$ comes into the picture because these roots are not real and $1 \pm \mathrm{i}\sqrt{3}$ will be handy in representing them.)
I'm not justifying any of that because it should be straightforward...  If not, let me know.

Comment: THanks for your effort. So i find the minimal polynomial of an algebraic number then do the factorization. Dont know how this will lead to what i want. and how to use  roots of unity to describe complex numbers.Cant find the connection to all these Im self studying and got finals in 2 days .And i though i understood theory but im stuck on excercises.And cant find examples to get things started.